# How to use checkbox with wpalchemy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used following code to create a checkbox in WordPress pages (in admin section):

```
<?php while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('sidebar-block')): ?>
<?php $mb->the_group_open(); ?>

    <!-- Some more code here for other fields -->

    <p class="checkbox">
    <input name="<?php $metabox->the_name('blue-block'); ?>" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if ($metabox->get_the_value('blue-block')) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>>
    <label>Do not use Blue Block for content</label>
    </p>

<?php $mb->the_group_close(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Above code is working fine. My question is how can i check if this checkbox is checked on the main website (frontend)?

Following is the code in my template for frontend:

```
<?php
    $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_sidebar_meta',TRUE);
    if ($my_meta['sidebar-block']) {
    foreach ($my_meta['sidebar-block'] as $sidebar)
    {
?>
<div id="aside-blue">
    <?php if ($sidebar['side_heading']) { ?>
        <h2 class="sideheading"><?php echo $sidebar['side_heading']; ?></h2>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $sidebar['side_content'] ); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to add `id="aside-blue"` only when checkbox is checked.

---

i tried following code for this, but it's not working

```
<?php
    $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_sidebar_meta',TRUE);
    if ($my_meta['sidebar-block']) {
    foreach ($my_meta['sidebar-block'] as $sidebar)
    {
?>

<div <?php if ($sidebar['blue-block'] == 'yes') { ?>id="aside-blue"<?php } ?>>

</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the wp_postmeta table how the value is stored. When I used checkboxes, the values were serialized. You'll probably need to [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it before using the meta value.